# use webservice datatype in referenced assembly

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, assemblies

Im working on a Web-Application (MyWebApp). I have a Service-Reference to a WCF-Webservice. The Servicereference is named "MyService". If I use Types from the Service I use them like "MyService.MyType".

Now however I want to outsource some helper-methods to an assembly (MyAssembly). To do this I created a DLL-Project, added the Service-Reference "MyService" and referenced the compiled assembly to my Web-Application.

Now if I want to pass an Object of type "MyType" to an outsourced function that expects "MyType" it says *"Argument 1: cannot convert from '**MyWebApp.MyService.MyType**' to '**MyAssembly.MyService.MyType**'"*

How can I fix this? It's the same service, so it must be a identifier-problem.

Comment: That isn't an identifier problem; the two service references are completely unrelated, even if they were in the same namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the service reference from MyWebApp.Since you have two service reference in both of projects, they are generating the same classes under different namespaces.

Comment: thanks! that was easy :-)
th only webservice i have to use is the one from the assembly. perfect :-)
using MyService = MyAssembly.MyService; will help ...